# Any finitely generated algebra over a field is a quotient of the polinomial algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

Assume $k$ is a field and $k[a_1,\dots,a_n]$ is a finetely generated algebra over $k$.

Is $k[a_1,\dots,a_n]$ a quotient of the polinomial algebra $k[x_1,\dots,x_m]$ for some $m\in\mathbb N$?

Is the argument in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/416231/every-finitely-generated-algebra-over-a-field-is-a-jacobson-ring/578658?noredirect=1#comment1721122_578658) sound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean your algebra is commutative, right? Then, yes, it follows from the **universal property of polynomial rings** over a field. And it holds for $m = n$ (and larger $m$'s).